# How to improve performance of this aggregate query?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-3.2

I have the following tables in MongoDB:

1. Users table (count 200+ users):

   ```
   {
   "_id" : ObjectId("56dd6204ce47a3c44d8b4567"),
   "u_role" : "1",
   "u_fname" : "dsfsd",
   "u_lname" : "dsfdsf",
   "u_email" : "dsfds@sfds.df",
   "u_password" : "$2y$10$/sGOrJNJHsgE1buAvVfObObgsRxA/KquVcJzUdMwoKjGsbyQDuXCq",
   "u_phone" : "sdfsdf",
   "u_dealer_name" : "dsfdff",
   "u_code" : "dsfdf",
   "u_dealer_phone" : "sdf",
   "u_address" : "sdfdsf",
   "u_city" : "dsfdf",
   "u_state" : "sdfdsf",
   "u_country_id" : "1",
   "u_zip_code" : "dsfdf",
   "u_forgot_token" : "",
   "u_status" : NumberLong(9),
   "updated_at" : ISODate("2016-07-13T05:57:10.196Z"),
   "created_at" : ISODate("2016-03-07T11:12:04.647Z"),
   "u_id" : "56dd6204ce47a3c44d8b4567",
   "coordinates" : [
       0,
       0
   ]}
   ```
2. User sales table (count 50,00,000+ records):

   ```
   {
   "_id" : ObjectId("56fce996ce47a3e0448b4590"),
   "us_u_id" : "56f32ca1ce47a323638b4567",
   "us_dealer_u_id" : "56f32ca1ce47a323638b4567",
   "us_corporate_dealer_u_id" : "56f32ca1ce47a323638b4567",
   "us_oem_u_id" : "1459249076s48FgbBXG4",
   "us_part_number" : "002005973000",
   "us_sup_part_number" : "",
   "us_alter_part_number" : "",
   "us_qty" : NumberLong(0),
   "us_sale_qty" : NumberLong(1),
   "us_date" : "20160321",
   "us_source_name" : "BOMAG",
   "us_source_address" : "",
   "us_source_city" : "",
   "us_source_state" : "",
   "us_zip_code" : "",
   "us_alternet_source_code" : "",
   "updated_at" : ISODate("2016-03-31T09:10:46.798Z"),
   "created_at" : ISODate("2016-03-31T09:10:46.798Z")
   }
   ```

My search query is:

```
db.hh_users.aggregate(
[
  {
    "$geoNear": {
      "near": {
        "coordinates": [
          77.3847,
          17.7284
        ]
      },
      "distanceField": "dist",
      "spherical": true,
      "limit": 192
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "u_status": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "hh_user_sales",
      "localField": "u_id",
      "foreignField": "us_dealer_u_id",
      "as": "usersales"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$usersales"
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "u_fname": "$u_fname",
      "u_lname": "$u_lname",
      "u_dealer_phone": "$u_dealer_phone",
      "u_email": "$u_email",
      "u_city": "$u_city",
      "u_state": "$u_state",
      "updated_at": "$updated_at",
      "us_part_number": {
        "$toLower": [
          "$usersales.us_part_number"
        ]
      },
      "us_qty": "$usersales.us_qty",
      "us_dealer_u_id": "$usersales.us_dealer_u_id",
      "dist": "$dist"
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "us_part_number": {
        "$in": [
          "va32a4000400",
          null,
          null,
          null,
          null
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "u_fname": {
        "$last": "$u_fname"
      },
      "u_lname": {
        "$last": "$u_lname"
      },
      "u_dealer_phone": {
        "$last": "$u_dealer_phone"
      },
      "u_email": {
        "$last": "$u_email"
      },
      "u_city": {
        "$last": "$u_city"
      },
      "u_state": {
        "$last": "$u_state"
      },
      "updated_at": {
        "$last": "$updated_at"
      },
      "dist": {
        "$last": "$dist"
      },
      "_id": {
        "us_dealer_u_id": "$us_dealer_u_id"
      },
      "us_part_number": {
        "$last": "$us_part_number"
      },
      "us_qty": {
        "$last": "$us_qty"
      },
      "us_dealer_u_id": {
        "$last": "$us_dealer_u_id"
      },
      "part1_qty": {
        "$max": {
          "$cond": [
            {
              "$eq": [
                "$us_part_number",
                null
              ]
            },
            "$us_qty",
            0
          ]
        }
      },
      "part2_qty": {
        "$max": {
          "$cond": [
            {
              "$eq": [
                "$us_part_number",
                null
              ]
            },
            "$us_qty",
            0
          ]
        }
      },
      "part3_qty": {
        "$max": {
          "$cond": [
            {
              "$eq": [
                "$us_part_number",
                null
              ]
            },
            "$us_qty",
            0
          ]
        }
      },
      "part4_qty": {
        "$max": {
          "$cond": [
            {
              "$eq": [
                "$us_part_number",
                null
              ]
            },
            "$us_qty",
            0
          ]
        }
      },
      "part5_qty": {
        "$max": {
          "$cond": [
            {
              "$eq": [
                "$us_part_number",
                null
              ]
            },
            "$us_qty",
            0
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "u_fname": "$u_fname",
      "u_lname": "$u_lname",
      "u_dealer_phone": "$u_dealer_phone",
      "u_email": "$u_email",
      "u_city": "$u_city",
      "u_state": "$u_state",
      "updated_at": "$updated_at",
      "us_part_number": "$us_part_number",
      "us_qty": "$us_qty",
      "us_dealer_u_id": "$us_dealer_u_id",
      "part1_qty": "$part1_qty",
      "part2_qty": "$part2_qty",
      "part3_qty": "$part3_qty",
      "part4_qty": "$part4_qty",
      "part5_qty": "$part5_qty",
      "total": {
        "$add": [
          "$part1_qty",
          "$part2_qty",
          "$part3_qty",
          "$part4_qty",
          "$part5_qty"
        ]
      },
      "dist": "$dist"
    }
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      "part1_qty": -1,
      "part2_qty": -1,
      "part3_qty": -1,
      "part4_qty": -1,
      "part5_qty": -1,
      "total": -1,
      "dist": 1,
      "us_qty": -1
    }
  },
  {
    "$skip": 0
  },
  {
    "$limit": 10
  }
]
).pretty()
```

It's taking more than 2 minutes to complete. How can I improve its performance?

Purpose of query is:

I need to search 5 parts at a time, join two tables (users and user sales) and get maximum parts quantity on top, and also total of parts is maximum.

Below Index I have set already.

users table :- u_id

users sales table :- u_dealer_id,us_part_number

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: I want to reduce query execution time

Comment: what are your indexes?

Comment: @AsyaKamsky please check I have edit my question

Comment: that's not possible - you have to have at least a geo index to be able to use geoNear on users.  You can get all indexes via db.<coll>.getIndexes()

Answer (score 0):

You need to start by using the [Explain Results](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/explain-results/) functionality to find out what the query plan is, and whether it is using any indexes or not at every stage.